# Method for creating many-to-one Relationships between custom posts and a single user?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I would like to create a many-to-one relationship between a custom post type and a user.

The custom post type is a form that users fill out when logged in, which then populates metadata on the post (is this the best way?).  The custom post is then associated with the user and can be viewed from a custom template page.

What is the best way to associate many custom posts with that user?

Should I use the built in author functionality or should I use some custom object stuff or even a custom plugin with database rows?

I usually do this in an ORM style system with Flask or Django, but this client is using WordPress.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't seen it already I would have a look at the [posts-to-posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin.  It allows association between users and posts.  the documentation for post<>users code examples [is here](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Posts-2-Users).